# Derived constructor signature refactoring

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I have a base class which takes in constructor arguments. I've added another one in, but now I have to change the base class in the derived classes.

Is there anyway in Resharper I can add this dependency into derived classes easily? I have about 1000 derived classes and wondering how to do this easily.

Thanks

Comment: This is a fairly narrow use case, and would be dangerous anyway unless it read your mind. I think the answer is no, personally i have never seen a feature like this

Comment: This is yet another reason to favor composition over inheritance...